# Cordova Android OS 5.0 - No Network Access

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

After our latest update for Android it seems that our Android 5.0 users are not able to utilize the app. I cannot recreate the issue on my Android 5.1 or 6.0 phones and all of our complaints have been from 5.0 users which luckily isn't widely used.

The last update focused on moving from parse.com to our hosted parse server on Heroku. We updated the Parse JS SDK to 1.9.2 and pointed the server url to our new heroku app, things seem to be going very well for everyone else.

The actual error users are seeing is: `Error: XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API` but the actual cordova app seems to be loading. It seems like something is blocking access to our heroku app on Android 5.0

We have the whitelist plugin installed with:

```
      <access origin="*"/>
      <allow-intent href="*"/>
      <allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Also using Cordova Android@5.2.2

Any ideas why my Android 5.0 users are having a hard time but everyone else is happy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please try `https://myapp.com/parse` to `https://www.myapp.com/parse` **or** just change **HTTPS** to **HTTP** and please install white list plugin for cordova

Comment: @Naitik It is currently set to something similar to https://www.myapp.com/parse/ and working fine for many users that aren't on OS 5.0. Any idea why just Android OS 5.0 might be affected?